# Does Oranguru's Instruct work if the Pokémon it points to faints before the move?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

If Oranguru tries to use Instruct but the Pokémon it chose to point to faints before the move, does Instruct work or not?

For example, suppose the following situation:

1. Salamence used Draco Meteor
2. Salamence fainted.
3. Oranguru used Instruct (and is going to use Draco Meteor)

In this case, does the move Instruct succeed or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instruct does not work like Copycat. Instruct causes the target to immediately use the last move they used, so in your case it would fail for two reasons:

- Instruct would have no target
- Even if Instruct could target a fainted Pokémon, the Pokémon would not be able to use any move as it is fainted

Comment: Nice, thanks. And I just noticed it is Dra**c**o Meteor!